# Apple Mach-O Linker Warning. lib/libxyz.a missing required architecture i386 in file lib/libxyz.a

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

i am new to Apple iOS development. I am trying to create static library and add it to Main  application.

- Created Library Project and added it as a dependency project to the Main application. It works.
- Now I took the lib.a (static library) from the Library project (present under debug-iphoneos) and copied to Main application. Tested the Main application - it works.

Now when i tried to copy the Main application to some other location (or even change the folder name - in which Main application is present) and try to run on Simulator, then i get following error:
ignoring file /Users/.../lib.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/.../lib.a

I don't really understand the relation/dependency on the path.

Comment: Though I'm not sure which library are you referring, there are some library files that may not have i386 architecture (simulator). Try it on device.

Comment: I have created my own static library. the static library works without an issue, when the static library project is added as a dependency project and static library (.a) is added to the Main application. But when I try to change the location of the Main appliation, XCode starts complaining that the (.a) static library is  missing i386 architecture :(

Answer (score 1):

the problem is solved.

I am using XCode 5.0.2 and iOS 7. when ever i compile the static library, the Xcode says it is building a universal library (but it is actually not). The 'Products' directory shows libxyz.a (which is in iphoneos/ directory) - this is actually for ARM6 & ARM7 for iPhone device. So when i took this 'libxyz.a' file and used it in another projects the linker used to throw a warning ' missing required architecture i386 '.

i have followed http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial

used the script to generate single binary which contains both simulator & iphone device binary.

```
# define output folder environment variable
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

# Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions
xcodebuild -target ImageFilters ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"
xcodebuild -target ImageFilters -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"

# make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# Step 2. Create universal binary file using lipo
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a"

# Last touch. copy the header files. Just for convenience
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/include" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"
```

Comment: although it works, be careful the script does not capture errors from the child builds.  so if the status of one of the xcodebuilds is false, it will still say build succeeded.